# php regex catch text after

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex:

```
$pattern = '!(>+\h+)?(.*)schrieb:(.*?)!iUgs';
```

to match

```
Daniel schrieb:
> I think
```

That works. But when I have more than one matching target

```
Daniel schrieb:
> I think 

Hi,
Jessi schrieb:
> I do
test
```

the second match will end up in the last catching group, but it should be matched again (but the whole followup, including the second match should be in the last catching group). Is that possible?

I Want to capture

```
1: Daniel
```

and

```
2: 
> I think 

Hi,
Jessi schrieb:
> I do
test
```

and after that

```
1: Jesse
```

and

```
2:
> I do
test
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/64Rr52/2

Comment: Or better - what is the final result you expect?

Comment: like here: https://regex101.com/r/64Rr52/3 but then it should match "Jessi schrieb" etc. again like the one before

Comment: Try [`$pattern = '~(?m)^.*schrieb:\R\h*>.*(?:\R(?!\R).*)*~i'`](https://regex101.com/r/5JEl16/3) to get the blocks in between double line breaks.

Comment: none of this works, because I want to capture everything after the "schrieb", so it needs to be captured two times, maybe its not possible

Comment: I updated my question to illustrate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex in PHP:

```
~^(.*?)\h+schrieb:(?=((?s).*\z))~im
```

`(?=((?s).*\z))` is a lookahead that does lookahead assertion and groups text after `schrieb:` till end of file.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/64Rr52/5)